# Using OGNL to get parameters

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, el, ognl

In one JSP page, I am including another JSP page and passing a parameter:

```
<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/somepage.jsp" flush="true">
    <jsp:param name="location" value="menu"/>
</jsp:include>
```

In the included page, I can access the parameter using EL. This works:

```
${param.location}
```

But I cannot use the OGNL equivalent to get the same parameter. None of these work:

```
#parameters.location
#parameters['location']
%{#parameters.location}
%{#parameters['location']}
```

I know there is a work-around using `<s:set var="location">${param.location}</s:set>` or `<c:set var="location">${param.location}</c:set>` and then using OGNL: `#location` but I want to avoid that. I don't want to use scriptlets either.

Comment: How are you *actually* trying to use the OGNL?

Comment: @dave_newton I need to use it in a number of places, e.g.: `<s:if test='%{#parameters.location=="menu"}'>` but even when I just try to display the parameter value on the JSP it does not work.

Comment: Set parameter in the result.

Comment: What about `${param.location}`? The issue is that there's no value stack AFAICR, same as with `<s:include>`.

Comment: I think what Dave recommends should work since it will use plain EL. More precisely there is a value stack but when jsp:param is used it temporarily overrides the parameter map, which is active only for the duration of the include. The value stack points to the original parameter map and so isn't able to see the difference. How EL knows I'm not sure... see: http://www.coderanch.com/t/177837/java-Web-Component-SCWCD/certification/scope-jsp-param the reply by Charles Lyons, I'll check just to be sure.

Comment: Struts2 tags don't support EL anymore. So I guess I'll just have to make do with `<s:set var="location">${param.location}</s:set>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Struts2 equivalent to the include tag is [`<s:include>`](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/include-tag.html) that's what you should replace in your code, then apply [`<s:param>`](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/param-tag.html) to parametrize it.

```
<s:include value="/WEB-INF/somepage.jsp">
    <s:param name="location" value="menu"/>
</s:include>
```

after that you can use OGNL.

Comment: and how you can read it?: #parameters.location #parameters['location'] %{#parameters.location} or %{#parameters['location']} ?